# list of fonts for a pdf and .indd file

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf

I have to make an application which can get the list of fonts for a pdf and .indd file in an excel sheet. After lot of research I came to know that with C# it is not possible.I came across Indesign Navigator API in Visual Studio which can be integrated to the VS IDE. Iam aware of C#, javascript is there any way by which this could be made and can be run on MAC and windows OS both.  Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by saving a text file out of InDesign and Acrobat with the font information. You could probably use extendscript to do this. The text file can then be imported easily into Excel as a csv or text file (whitespace delimited).

You weren't very clear about what your intentions are, but here's an example of a javascript that can pull font information out of InDesign to save a list of fonts for a document.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var docFonts = doc.fonts.everyItem().getElements();

var fileContents = "";
for (var i=0; i < docFonts.length; i++) {
   var font = docFonts[i];
   fileContents += font.name + "\n";
};

var newFilePath = doc.filePath + "/" + doc.name.replace(/\.indd/,'') + "_fonts.txt";
var newFile = File(newFilePath);

newFile.open('w')

newFile.write(fileContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible approach...
It is possible to write out an XML representation of an InDesign file...

To generate IDML, `choose File > Export Format: InDesign Markup (INDML)`...

This is a zip with all the information.

There is a folder `Resources` which contains `Fonts.xml` (Resources: Fonts.xml)

This can be parsed cross-plattform because it just XML...

Here you find a description of the anatomy of a INDML InDesign Document...
http://www.indesignsecrets.com/downloads/Anatomy_of_IDML.pdf

Hope this helps...